# Can windows distinguish 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs?

Tags: windows, dll, path, 32bit-64bit

Should Windows applications generally be able to distinguish between two DLLs with the same name, one being 32-bit and one being 64-bit, if they're in two separate paths in the system PATH variable?

Specifically right now, I have 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs for FreeImage, and they're in two separate folders, `free_image_path\dist32` and `free_image_path\dist64`, both of which I've added to the system PATH. However, application built to use them can't find either and I'm wondering if this is because there's two DLLs with the same name and they can't distinguish them.

I also tried putting the 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs in the windows\system and windows\SySWoW64 folders respectively, and that worked for the 32-bit app but not the 64-bit.

Thanks.

Comment: You say: "putting the 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs in the windows\system and windows\SySWoW64 folders, respectively". [Confusingly, this is exactly backwards.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)

Comment: Ah-hah! That might explains things. I was just haphazardly trying things at that point because my original attempt to add two new paths, dist32 and dist64 hadn't worked. I'll try switching these around.

Comment: This question is also relevant for the Simple Directmedia Layer (SDL) DLLs; i.e. SDL2.dll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows can tell whether a given DLL is compiled for 32 bit or 64 bit platforms, but that won't help in the situation you describe.  The DLL loader for your app process will stop looking as soon as it finds a DLL in the system path that fits the *file name* requirements for the DLL import.  There are no other qualifications for matching *code* DLLs. (as noted in the comments, non-code resource DLLs are a different story. I suspect resource DLLs are not loaded by the core program loader but by a resource manager with different rules and objectives.)

If the first DLL in the path is 32 bit and your app is 32 bit, then the DLL load will work.  If the app is 64 bit, it will fail to load the DLL and the process will abort.

If you want two DLLs to coexist on the system path, you need to give them unique file names.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this is untrue (that "it will fail to load the DLL"). It depends *how* you use the DLL(s). It is for example well possible to use an x64 DLL as resource DLL of an x86 process and vice versa. Once code is involved, you are obviously right in all other points.

Comment: Hmm, it's 99% true.  Let's make that 100% on the nose for this question, FreeImage is a library.

Comment: As Craig pointed out in a comment above, I had placed the DLLs in the wrong system folders; I switched them around, and it is working now. I've marked this as the answer though since my question was more generally about whether applications can distinguish like-named DLLs based on the DLLs alone, not what particular paths they're in.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, guys.  I've updated the answer to be specific to code dlls, and noted that resource dlls are a different animal.

Comment: I'd suggest updating this answer to include the approach using `\windows\system32` and `\windows\syswow64`, as this is likely the best solution; regardless of whether it alone answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to putting the 64-bit dll in `\windows\system32` and the 32-bit one in `\windows\syswow64`, I have found that it also works if you put the 32-bit one in a subdirectory of `\Program Files (x86)` and the 64-bit one in the corresponding subdirectory of `\Program Files`, with both of those subdirectories included in PATH.